# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in my js file

Tags: javascript

```
$(document).ready(fuction( {

    $('.nav').click(function( {
        $('.div3').animate({height:'100px'}, 500);
    });

    $('.abcd1').mousedown(function() {
        var a1m = document.getElementById('abcd_1');
        a1m.currentTime = 0;
        a1m.play();
    });
});
```

I am getting this error on line `/* $('.nav').click(function( { */` and I am unable to figure out where I went wrong.

Comment: Your first line `$(document).ready(fuction( {`, Instead of `fuction` it should be `function`

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is `function()` so change:

`$(document).ready(fuction( {` to `$(document).ready(function() {` (you forgot the N of function here too)

and `$('.nav').click(function( {` to `$('.nav').click(function() {`